# How can I create an indefinite iterations of objects in python?

Tags: python, list, class, oop, object

I'm new to python and am trying to create a program to test some methods of object creation. Currently, I'm writing a program that involves creating objects, giving them a unique numeric variable, and assigning them to a list for future referencing. Here's what I wrote to create the variable names:

```
def getRectangleName():
    rectName = list("Rectangle")
    SPAWNEDOBJECTLIST.append(len(SPAWNEDOBJECTLIST))
    rectName.append(str(len(SPAWNEDOBJECTLIST)))
    return rectName
```

and then that's passed onto something to turn that string into a variable name. I tried eval(), learned this was Bad for some reason and it didn't work anyway, and tried some workarounds to no avail.

I figure there's plenty of games that have an indefinite number of characters on the screen. Is there an established way of making iterations of objects like this?

The objects themselves have an X and Y so that they act as reference points for the display of rectangles on screen(the idea in the future is to have each one move around on their own, so simply making lists of X and Y to draw rectangles isn't useful).

**Edit:** The problem is that I don't know how to give each object its own variable to put it on a list for future referencing.

**Edit2:** I don't think I'm asking the right question, actually, or using the right terminology. I need to be able to have an indefinite number of objects created on the fly after the program is already running, and be able to reference them individually.

Comment: Do you need to address each by name, for could for example just have a list of objects instead?

Comment: What's wrong with using a `dict` to map rectangle names to rectangle objects?

Comment: Also, you might want to call your function something else. If I were calling a function called `getRectangleNumber` I would expect a number to be returned, not a `list`.

Comment: Can you give an example of some code that *uses* a rectangle object? The code you posted needs some more context.

Comment: Go through this: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ Ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Append all the objects to a list so you can iterate through them or add them to a dictionary with sequential numbers and delete entries as they become unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dynamically want to create variables and add them to class instances, use this

```
class MainClass:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value

def getRectangleNameGenerator(N = 10):
    X = 0
    while X <= N:
        X += 1
        yield "Rectangle" + str(X)
RectangleName = getRectangleNameGenerator()

ClassInstances = {next(RectangleName) : MainClass}
ClassInstances[next(RectangleName)] = MainClass

ClassInstances["Rectangle1"].Temp = 10
print ClassInstances["Rectangle1"].Temp
```

If the class is going to have only X and Y,

```
class MainClass:
    X, Y = 0, 0

def getRectangleNameGenerator(N = 10):
    X = 0
    while X <= N:
        X += 1
        yield "Rectangle" + str(X)
RectangleName = getRectangleNameGenerator()

ClassInstances = {next(RectangleName) : MainClass}
ClassInstances[next(RectangleName)] = MainClass

ClassInstances["Rectangle1"].X = 11
print ClassInstances["Rectangle1"].X
```

Answer (score 5):

> The problem is that I don't know how to give each object its own variable to put it on a list for future referencing.

Whenever you think you need variables you didn't type into your program, you're doing something wrong. You don't need to assign something to a variable to put it on a list:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]                 # Note how I don't assign 1, 2, or 3 to variables.
x.append(4)                   # 4 doesn't get a variable either.
x.append(make_a_rectangle())  # We create a rectangle and stick it on the list.
do_stuff_with(x[4])           # We pass the rectangle to a function.

x = []                            # New list.
for i in xrange(n):
    x.append(make_a_rectangle())  # This happens n times.
# At this point, we have n rectangles, none of them associated with their own
# variable, none of them with a name.
```

If you think you need names for things (and quite often, you don't really need the names), you can use a dict:

```
x = {}
x['foo'] = make_a_rectangle()
do_stuff_with(x['foo'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great idea to combine the function of *managing* the rectangles -- accessing, adding, or deleting them -- with the idea of *being* rectangles. You never know when you might need to maintain multiple lists, or change from unordered lists to organized ones.

Until you really need more, keep the management functions simple: use built-in lists or dictionaries.  Use lists if you just care about ordering, or only need to know you have a bunch of stuff:

```
class Rectangle (object): 
    def __init__(self, top, bottom, left, right):
       self.Top = top
       self.Left = left
       self.Right = right
       self.Bottom = bottom

list_of_rects = [Rectangle(10,0,0,10), Rectangle(20, 10, 10 ,20)]

# how many rects?  
len(list_of_rects)
# result: 2


# where is this particular rect?
fred = Rectangle(30,20,20, 30)
list_of_rects.insert(fred, 1)
list_of_rects.index(fred)
# result: 1

#remove an item from the list:
list_of_rects.remove(fred)

#search the list:
right_of_5 = [rect for rect in list_of_rects if rect.Left > 5]
```

If you need to get access to the individual rects for some reason -- 'what's the rectangle of the goal' or something -- you have two choices:

1) the code that needs the rect just keeps a reference to it:

```
class Goal(object):
   def __init__(self, rect):
      self.Rect = rect

goalrect =  Rectangle (0,0,20,20)
mygoal = Goal(goalrect)
list_of_rects.append(goalrect)

# now goalrect always knows about it's own rect, but the list can keep track of it too...
```

2) Or, use a dictionary:

```
named_rects = {}
named_rects['goal'] = Rectangle(0,0,20,20)
```

You get all the same abilities with a dictionary that you do with a list -- add, delete, and find -- **except** dictionaries don't preserve order, so you can't manage things like priority:

```
# add to the dict:
named_rects['new_rect'] = Rectangle(90,90,95,95)

# remove
del named_rects['new_rect']

# find = is there a known key?
if 'new_rect' in named_rects: print new_rect

# search:
right_of_5 = [rect for rect in named_rects.items() if rect.Left > 5]
```

There are cases where you need fancier things than plain old lists and dicts -- but always try it with the free stuff first :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to refer to your rectangle instances by name, I would suggest to keep a dictionary at class level. Something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from threading import Lock
import random

class Rectangle:
    instances = {}
    lock = Lock ()

    @classmethod
    def forName (cls, name):
        return cls.instances [name] if name in cls.instances else None

    @classmethod
    def push (cls, inst):
        with cls.lock:
            name = None
            while not name or name in cls.instances:
                name = ''.join (random.choice ('abcdefghij') for i in range (16) )
            cls.instances [name] = inst
            return name

    def __init__ (self):
        self.name = Rectangle.push (self)


names = [Rectangle ().name for i in range (5) ]

for name in names:
    print (name, Rectangle.forName (name) )
```